# I Have an error in MySQL. Show me a syntaxt error in my query

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have this query in MySQL

```
create function is_prime(num int) returns boolean
begin
    declare cont;
    set cont = 2;

    while(cont != num) do
        if (num % cont = 0) then
            return false;
        end if;
        cont = cont + 1;
    end while;

    return true;
end//
```

VSCode show a syntaxt error. I have checked each line but i dont look the error.
Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: declare cont has no data type.

Comment: You have not defined the type of cont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaration has to have a datatype

Also you forgot to Set the increase

```
DELIMITER //
create function is_prime(num int) returns boolean
begin
    declare cont INTEGER;
    set cont = 2;

    while(cont != num) do
        if (num % cont = 0) then
            return false;
        end if;
        SET cont := cont + 1;
    end while;

    return true;
end//
```